# Renaming a script using Linux mv / rename

Tags: linux, shell, rename

I'm trying to rename the script *audience_segment_map.sh* to *audience_segment_map_dedupe.sh* using the Linux command line.

I have tried using the `mv` and the `rename` commands but they're not having the desired effect:

```
mv user/local/dmp_job/audience_segment_map.sh user/local/dmp_job/audience_segment_map_deupe.sh
```

This returns the error

> 'audience_segment_map.sh' No such file or directory"

but when I use the `ls` command, the file clearly shows up.

How should I proceed?

Comment: can you display permissions on the file using ls -l ?

Comment: Additionally, I tried the mv command as root usr (sudo su)

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? `user/local/.../...` is different from `/user/local/.../...` with a leading `/`

Comment: Hi @HichemBOUSSETTA here are the permissions rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff  330 May 14 21:18 audience_segment_map.sh

Comment: @JasonKLai that was the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JasonKLai Please post that as an answer and ping me [at]Fabby and I''ll come back and upvote.

Comment: Thanks @Fabby , I posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

Pointing to a path with and without leading `/` slashes are different (absolute versus relative, respectively). Unless you are in the root directory, most likely you want your command to look like

```
mv /user/local/dmp_job/audience_segment_map.sh /user/local/dmp_job/audience_segment_map_deupe.sh
```

where the path is pointing to `/user/local/...` instead of `user/local/...`

Comment: As promised!  **:-)**